# Initialize std::tuple in member initializer list of a class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a tuple as a member of template class, I'd like to initialize the `std::tuple` when I construct instance of class.

```
template <typename ...Type>
struct Boundary {
    std::tuple<Type...> lower_boundary, upper_boundary;
    Boundary() : lower_boundary(), upper_boudary(){}
}
```

for `lower_boundary` and `upper_boundary`, I want to initialize each element to `numeric_limits<type for that element>::min()` or `max()`. Is there any way I can do that in the member initialize list? I know I can set it in constructor, I'm looking for other approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about e.g.

```
Boundary()
    : lower_boundary(std::numeric_limits<Type>::min()...),
      upper_boundary(std::numeric_limits<Type>::max()...)
    {}
```